# Determining irreducible components of $Z(y^4 - x^6, y^3 - x y^2 - y x^3 + x^4) \subset \mathbb A^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to determine the irreducible components of the zero set $Z(I)$ for the ideal $I = (y^4 - x^6,\, y^3 - x y^2 - y x^3 + x^4)$, in the affine space $\mathbb A^2$ over an algebraically closed field $k$.

I can factor $I = (y^2 - x^3)(y^2  +x^3,\, y - x)$, hence $Z(I) = Z(y^2 - x^3) \cup Z(y^2 + x^3,\, y - x)$, but I'm stuck trying to prove these ideals are prime (and is the second one even prime? If not, how do I reduce it further?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key fact that we will use to find the irreducible components is that an algebraic subset of a variety is irreducible iff its coordinate ring is an integral domain. Therefore, consider the coordinate ring of the algebraic set $Z(y^2 - x^3)$: it is $\frac{k[x,y]}{(y^2 - x^3)}$, which is an integral domain, hence $Z(y^2 - x^3)$ is irreducible.

In order to apply this fact to the second algebraic set, it must be simplified further:
$$
Z(y^2 + x^3, y-x) = Z(x^2 + x^3, y-x) = Z(x^2(x+1), y-x) = Z(x^2, y-x) \cup Z(x+1, y-x). 
$$
Now, $\frac{k[x,y]}{(x+1,y-x)} \simeq \frac{k[x]}{(x+1)} \simeq k$ is an integral domain, so $Z(x+1,y-x)$ is irreducible. Finally, the coordinate ring of $Z(x^2, y-x)$ is $\frac{k[x,y]}{(x,y-x)} \simeq k$, which is an integral domain, so $Z(x^2, y-x)$ is irreducible, as well (it's important here that, when constructing the coordinate ring of $Z(x^2,y-x)$, one takes the radical of the ideal $(x^2,y-x)$ rather than the ideal itself).

Therefore, we conclude that the irreducible components of $Z(y^4-x^6, y^3-xy^2-yx^3+x^4)$ are 
$$
Z(y^2 - x^3) \textrm{ and } Z(x^2, y-x) \textrm{ and } Z(x+1, y-x).
$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why $k[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3)$ is a domain?

Comment: One slick way to do so is to build an isomorphism $k[t^2,t^3] \simeq \frac{k[x,y]}{(y^2-x^3)}$ by sending $t^2 \mapsto x$ and $t^3 \mapsto y$, and then $k[t^2,t^3]$ is clearly a domain.

Comment: Can you explain the notation $k[t^2, t^3]$? I've always interpreted this as not a polynomial ring in the usual sense with independent variables $k[x,y] = (k[x])[y]$ but rather as precisely the quotient $k[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3)$, but then it's not obvious to me why it's a domain.

Comment: $k[t^2,t^3]$ is the ring of polynomials in $t^2$ and in $t^3$, so elements of this ring look like polynomials $a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + a_3 t^3 + \ldots a_n t^n$ so that $a_1 = 0$.

Comment: Another way to think about it is to take $k[x,y]$ and replace all of the $x$'s with $t^2$ and all of the $y$'s with $t^3$.

Comment: Okay, I get that. But why is it a domain? I get why a regular polynomial ring $R[X]$ is a domain if $R$ is, but in this case it feels like taking products can cause stuff to cancel out, since $(t^2)^3 = (t^3)^2$.

Comment: $k[t^2,t^3]$ is a subring of $k[t]$, so if you had zero divisors in $k[t^2,t^3]$, then you would also have them in $k[t]$, contradicting the fact that $k[t]$ is a domain.

Comment: @msteve: Notice that $Z(x+1,y-x)=\{(-1,-1)\}$ and $Z(x^2,y-x)=Z(x,y-x)=Z(x,y)=\{(0,0)\}$. Since $\{(0,0)\} \subseteq Z(y^2-x^3)$, you don't count it anymore. Therefore, we get $Z(y^2-x^3) \cup \{(-1,-1)\}$.